# When do we use "THE" before character name/nickname?

Tags: proper-nouns

For example: Why do we use "Wolverine" not "the Wolverine"

I want create character of the nameless man called Revenant. Should I use "Revenant" or "the Revenant"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But we *do* use [*The Wolverine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolverine_(film)), And some people, like Donald Trump, *do* put article in front of their names (*The Donald*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either to suit the style of the character, and hinges on the difference between being *called* something and being *named* something.

- **The Revenant** gives a feel of a nameless person, known only for his characteristics.  "The Stranger", "The Lost Man", "The One-Armed Man" are what others call someone.
- **Revenant** gives a feel of his nature or title has become his name, and conveys some closeness to him.

Some characters have changed in various incarnations, the first to come to mind is The Bat-Man ("the man who is like a bat") who eventually became named Batman.

I'd suggest your character is better as the Revenant.

Answer (score 1):

Usually superhero names are treated like other names.  Just like I don't say "I'm the James",  so Wolverine doesn't say "I'm the Wolverine".

Some superheroes use an adjective phrase, and it is normal to say, for example, "The Incredible Hulk", but "Hulk" for short (with no "the")

If your superhero character is "Revenant" then that is his/her name, and you don't need "the".

Comment: That's true. Then again... https://youtu.be/xJjCnWm5cvE?t=76.